# Modern site pages in SharePoint Online: Achieving full width

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages

I created a new modern Site Page in my SharePoint team site to become the homepage. I also changed the  tag to Home so I can remove the header.

I managed to get rid of the vertical navigation pane on the left by hiding it in the site sections. However one thing I noticed is that this page layout only takes 3/5 of the page from left to right. That is, the left of the page:

[image]

How can I actually stretch the page layout so it uses this wasted space?

Comment: I see the same thing when the quick launch is removed. I have no clue how to stretch it either :(

Comment: Hi pmdci: For Modern page, there is no OOTB feature to stretch the width to full screen, you can achieve it using SPFx https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/how-add-spfx-webpart-full-width-column

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found is to not use SharePoint. It's funny the header uses 100% of the width but it appears like a ridiculous ledge over the white space of the web parts below.
There's always an excuse for these gotchas and rarely, if ever, a fix.

The only other way is to use the pictureless formatting which tricks the eye into thinking it's using 100% of the page width.